# MySQL Unknown column issue

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here is my database structure

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B9ExyO6ktYcOenZ1WlBwdlY2R3c

My SQL query looks like that

```
SELECT
    u.fullname,
    a.id,
    a.content,
    a.addDT,
    a.`right`,
    acr.score,
    acr.checkDT
FROM
    answers a,
    users u
LEFT JOIN `answer_chk_results` acr ON acr.aid = a.id
WHERE
    a.qid = 7
AND u.id = a.uid
GROUP BY
    a.`right` DESC
```

Getting error message

`[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'a.id' in 'on clause'`

I'm pretty sure that a.id column exists

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't mix join syntax with comma delimited table syntax. If you are going to left join, you need to use an inner join for the other two tables.

```
SELECT
    u.fullname,
    a.id,
    a.content,
    a.addDT,
    a.`right`,
    acr.score,
    acr.checkDT
FROM
    answers a
    INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = a.uid
LEFT JOIN `answer_chk_results` acr ON acr.aid = a.id
WHERE
    a.qid = 7
GROUP BY
    a.`right` DESC
```

This *might* work also, but is not guranteed:

```
SELECT
    u.fullname,
    a.id,
    a.content,
    a.addDT,
    a.`right`,
    acr.score,
    acr.checkDT
FROM
    (answers a,
    users u)
LEFT JOIN `answer_chk_results` acr ON acr.aid = a.id
WHERE
    a.qid = 7
AND u.id = a.uid
GROUP BY
    a.`right` DESC
```